# How can I tell if my ISP account password is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, passwords

How can I be sure my ISP encrypts my account password?  I found out accidentally that mine did not.  I had called to report an interruption in service, and in the process of "troubleshooting", the tech read my password off to me!!  What can I do about this?

Comment: Switch ISPs. I'm not sure that you can do anything.

Comment: BTW- if it is encrypted, then they can decrypt it and read it. If it is HASHED, then they cannot decrypt it. They should be hashing, not encrypting.

Answer (score 1):

Other than calling them up and asking (and then hoping your contact knows what they're talking about), you cannot tell if the password is encrypted: anything that can be done with a plain-text password can be done with an encrypted password.

The best clue that the password is *hashed* (stored in a non-recoverable manner) is how they deal with forgotten passwords.  If they have you provide a new password or send you a temporary password, it's probably hashed.  If they can tell you what your password is, it's encrypted or stored in plain text.